# Creating a grid in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cc-2015

How do I create a grid in Illustrator, 7x5 with equal sized boxes? (Grid tool only allows 6x6)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you are doing wrong, but the grid tool is unlimited AFAIK.

6x4 dividers gives 7x5 boxes:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not certain what "7x5" refers to. Meters? Inches? Feet? Centimeters?

But... draw a rectangle that is "7x5", then with the rectangle selected choose `Object > Path > Split Into Grid` to set the divisions you want.

I'm *guessing* that you may be referring to **meters**. If that's the case you won't be able to create a 7 meter wide grid. 7 meters = 275.3 inches. Illustrator's *maximum* artboard size is 227 inches (5.7 meters). You will have to work at scale if you need art that large.